# pod mysql mount azure files failed

Tags: mysql, azure-storage, azure-aks

wanna deploy a mysql in cluster, and pod need a persistent storage, here are yaml & pictures:

The pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mysql:5.7
    name: mypod
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
        protocol: TCP
    env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: THEROODPWD
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /var/lib/mysql/
  volumes:
  - name: azure
    csi:
      driver: file.csi.azure.com
      volumeAttributes:
        secretName: williamstoragekey
        shareName: mysql
        mountOptions: "dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,cache=strict,actimeo=30"
```

The secret:

```
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: williamstoragekey
  namespace: default
  uid: 0e164956-2e2c-47ef-adc3-ffed8089a4a7
  resourceVersion: '20976434'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-03-14T07:13:38Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-create
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-03-14T07:13:38Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:data:
          .: {}
          f:azurestorageaccountkey: {}
          f:azurestorageaccountname: {}
        f:type: {}
data:
  azurestorageaccountkey: >-
    TWYrMFRaQ0ZLQVIxcEtVMFJGNUdCSEFGcXVnREdYZDZ5V2JMd2hFeGJFeTd0Z1pmNWNFQjM2d3FQM1EwY0VkeExRckhKWVZMZnJvYlN0QlIzcEJOeHc9PQ==
  azurestorageaccountname: a3ViZXRlc3RpbmcwMDk=
type: Opaque
```

The pod event:
[image]

And inside the file share:
[image]

Pod logs:
2022-03-15 01:07:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.37-1debian10 started.
2022-03-15 01:07:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-03-15 01:07:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.37-1debian10 started.
2022-03-15 01:07:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2022-03-15T01:07:35.308618Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-03-15T01:07:35.321413Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2022-03-15T01:07:35.321452Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

It's obviously the files inside mysql file share are created by mysql, and the file share is new created and is empty. But the pod seems crashed many times to start and terminated.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/770819/pod-mount-azure-files-failed.html

> > Posting the Microsoft Q&A thread(answered) discussion here,  which can benefits other community reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with Mysql:5.7 on AKS. I created azurefile volume and added it to the pod. My default azurefile class created a dir with dir_mode=0777 file_mode=0777 uid=0 gid=0 so I got dir with root owner and rwx for all users. The solution was to create another storage class that will create dir with mysql user as an owner and 750 chmod options.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: name-of-class
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0750
  - file_mode=0750
  - uid=999
  - gid=999
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```